How to get a object in a list using Min and Max together on two different columns in the same line query C#
I have a list:



ID
REST
AMOUNT




A
10
100


B
08
100


C
03
100


D
06
100


E
07
200


F
04
200


G
09
300


H
06
400


I
08
500



I've tried and didn't work:
var t = Mylist
    .GroupBy(f => new { f.ID,f.REST,f.AMOUNT })
    .Select(grp => new 
    { 
        id = grp.Key.ID, 
        Max = grp.Max(g => g.AMOUNT), 
        Min = grp.Min(g => g.REST) 
    })
    .ToList();


I also tried and didn't work:
var t = Mylist.OrderByDescending(e => e.REST).ThenBy(e => e.AMOUNT).First();


I need the line with minimum REST and maximum AMOUNT of the same line, ex:



ID
REST
AMOUNT




F
04
200




"didn't work" isn't a very helpful way of describing what happened with the approaches you've tried. Did the code fail to compile? Was an exception thrown? Did you not get the results you expected? Please edit your question with more details.

Your example result (line F) exhibits neither the minimum REST (which would be row C) nor the maximum AMOUNT (which would be row I). What are you actually trying to do here?

Exactly! It is not meant to be the minimum REST and the maximum AMOUNT of the entire collection, but rather the minimum REST linked to the maximum AMOUNT. I could get the (line C) | 03  | 100 - In that case the REST value is less than line F, but the AMOUNT is bigger than (line F). I hope I explained better. Thanks!

I'm assuming you want the minimum rest, and within any rows with the same minimum rest, the maximum amount. Please edit your question to clarify your requirements. If my assumption is right, then you've got the order wrong:
var t = Mylist.OrderBy(e => e.REST).ThenByDescending(e => e.AMOUNT).First();

You need ascending order of rest so that the first row has the minimum value; and conversely for amount.
Update
From your latest comment, I see that what you want is the maximum amount per unit rest. This gives you it:
var t = Mylist.MaxBy(e => (double)e.AMOUNT / e.REST);

or, equivalently, the minimum rest per unit amount:
var t = Mylist.MinBy(e => (double)e.REST / e.AMOUNT);

